# WordPress & External Page: 404 error in IE and some others

Tags: page-template

I'm working some API. Core is WordPress. Okay, let me paste a sample:

```
<?php 
include_once('../wp-blog-header.php');

$roll= esc_attr($_GET['roll']);

if ( $roll != "" ) {

$args = array(
    'meta_key'     => 'std_roll',
    'meta_value'   => $roll,
);

$blogusers = get_users($args);
    foreach ($blogusers as $user) {
        echo '<li>' . $user->user_login . '</li>';
}

}
```

This is working in FF, Chrome completely. But in IE, error 404 not found error. Same in .NET (in HttpWebRequest), and android (HttpGet) also.

When I moved the code in WordPress theme ( a page template), everything was working fine.

What was the problem and how that can be fixed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was solved using

```
<?php 
include_once('../wp-load.php');
```

Answer (score 0):

Just because you see something in the browser doesn't mean you don't get a 404. Browsers will display content of of a 404 page (if there is content) when it is longer then a browser specific length. It might be that IE requires longer length then the other browsers.

Why do you get a 404? hard to know without more detail about your setup but most likely the $_SERVER variable is not setup in a way wordpress expects for its configuration. Make sure all the URL related keys are filled correctly.